# Cannot retrieve product using product key from Stripe [nextjs, stripe]

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, react-stripe

I need to retrieve data from Stripe using a product key. Is there a solution to achieve this, or is there an error in my method?

```
export const getProduct = async (productKey: string): Promise<Stripe.Product> => {
  const { serverRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

  const stripe = new Stripe(serverRuntimeConfig.STRIPE_KEY!, {
    apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
  });

  try {
    const product = await stripe.products.retrieve(productKey);
    return product;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error retrieving product:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Comment: Assuming the `productKey` contains a valid product ID that belongs to your Stripe account, then this should work. If it doesn't, can you share the exact error message you see?

Comment: Also you need to make sure this code is running on your backend using your secret API key.